# Pop-up on hovering over a table cell <-- Is this possible in JavaScript? If so, How?

Tags: javascript, popup, hover, cell

I've displayed a table of used-items for sale.

I'd like to let used just hover-over an item's table-cell,
to display item's price, eg, in a pop-up text-box.

Is this possible in JavaScript?

If I'd need the (row, col) (eg, in another location format)
how to get those?

Comment: can we some code that you have written

Answer (score 14):

You don't need Javascript for this: you could use a `title` attribute for each item.

```
<td title="Title">Item<!-- Will display a tooltip with "Title" on hover --></td>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HgYVC/1/)

Comment: FYI, the jsfiddle link doesn't go to a fiddle you have saved.